# Google Analytics fails on startup

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I follow the tutorial on enabling Google Analytics for one of my apps.
This seems to work fine for API level 17 and a Samsung Galaxy 4.

However, when installing the app on an old API Level 4 G1, the app fails with the following error:

```
Uncaught handler: thread client_id_fetcher exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ApplicationContext.openFileOutput(ApplicationContext.java:405)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
  at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ClientIdDefaultProvider.storeClientId(ClientIdDefaultProvider.java:102)
  at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ClientIdDefaultProvider.generateClientId(ClientIdDefaultProvider.java:123)
  at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ClientIdDefaultProvider.initializeClientId(ClientIdDefaultProvider.java:179)
  at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ClientIdDefaultProvider$1.run(ClientIdDefaultProvider.java:134)
```

Are there API level requirements for Google Analytics for Android?

Comment: Personally, unless you have good reason reccomend you not even bother support devices still running on 1.6, as do the vast majority of the android development community #minSdkVersionFourteen

Comment: I usually do an install on an old device with a small screen to pinpoint layout and performance problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Readme included with Google Analytics V2 and the new [V3 Beta](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/) both state a minimum SDK of 2.1 (v7).

Comment: I totally missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @DKIT - you'd think it would be somewhere on their website, but nope: only in the Readme.